# How to read a variable defined in dbt_project.yml to a dbt .sql model configuration

Tags: dbt

How can we refer a variable defined in dbt_project.yml to a sql dbt model

```
vars:
  schema_name: "PUB"
```

The dbt .sql model code in which i want to refer this variable is in quoted between asterick below:

```
{{
  config(
      database= 'RND',
      schema= *schema_name*
  )
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify it one file at a time, you can do the following.

```
{{
  config(
      database= 'RND',
      schema= var('schema_name')
  )
}}
```